# How to get original token value of text using Nltk RegexTokenizer

Tags: python, nltk, tokenize

I am able to remove the punctuation from text using Nltk `RegExTokenizer`. I want to get the original index of `tokens` item from the original `masked_ocr_text` without punctuation removed.

How i can achieve it? Following is the code

```
tokenizer = nltk.RegexpTokenizer(r"\w+")
tokens=tokenizer.tokenize(masked_ocr_text)
actual_tokens = nltk.tokenizer.word_tokenize(masked_ocr_text)
```

For example :

```
masked_ocr_text = 'This is sample, in order to check!"
tokens = ['This','is',sample','in','order','to','check']
actual_tokens = ['This','is',sample',',','in','order','to','check','!']
```

I want to get the index from `actual_tokens` for some required `tokens` value.

Comment: Do you need `[x.span() for x in re.finditer(r'\w+', masked_ocr_text)]` ([demo](https://ideone.com/4lmDTt))?

Comment: can you explain what it does?

Comment: Gets the start and end positions of the regex matches.

Comment: Got it. I have updated the question to show the problem. Pls have a look. :)

Comment: What about `_`? What is expected in case of `simple_sample`? 1 single token or 3? Also, digits glued to letters? Float numbers? URLs, emails...?

Comment: For the `simple_sample` the `RegexpTokenizer` will show as `simple, sample`. I have to get the index directly from the masked_ocr_text or from the `actual_tokens` what ever possible.